# How to completely evenly light a 3D molecule model

Tags: light

I have a 3D model of a molucule with a camera that is rotating around it. I have tried adding lights here and there but I can´t get the model evenly lit. Whenever I render it, it looks good, but then also has some stupid dark spots from not being lit that I can´t get removed. Please help, as I am very new to blender.

(I want some minimal shadows, to better highlight the depth)

Comment: This might not be exactly your style, but the question is so similar.... https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220572/35559

Answer (score 0):

you can try mixing a BSDF shader with an emission node applied to the molecule: the emission shader will give some extra lights to the model (if you add too much emission the object will be flat with no shadow, so play with the right value of the strength of the emission)

[image]